# Replace \" with " in php

Tags: php, string

How to replace  `\"` with `"` from a string in php and to remove `\` from end of a string?
My line of code is like :

```
$field[] = str_replace('\\"', '"', trim($val, '\\'));
```

But this is not working..somebody please help me

Comment: What is your original string(content of `$val`) ?

Comment: so um stripslashes()

Comment: $val= "hell\"ooo\;

Comment: You want to replace "\ or \"? your question and your examples are contradictory

Comment: sorry ...it is \"..your answer really helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with default function - [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
$val = '"hell\"ooo\\';
echo stripslashes($val);
```

---

Or if you need with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$val = '"hell\"ooo\\';
echo str_replace('\\"', '"', trim($val, '\\'));
```

**Result** would be:

```
"hell"ooo
```